# OpenERP - how to get form field value in python code

Tags: odoo

I have a field in the XML file, categ_id. I need to access the value of that field in my Python code, in product_template class. I tried vals as a paremeter but it did not work.
If you can give me an example object.field_name as it relates to the case I have described.

Comment: Thank you Odedra. I am not sure I understand. I have a class product_template and I want inside the class to access value of the field categ_id. I am not sure what the object would be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried to elaborate more in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nebojsa - your question is not understandable at all, but I'll try to answer it. You can get the value of categ_id in two or even three ways:

- vals.get('categ_id') - this is the way to go when you are creating a new record or updating existing one with change in categ_id field - otherwise you'll get an error or NoneType defined.
- template = self.pool.get('product.template).browse(cr, uid, ids) and then template.categ_id.id - to get the value when you do have an id of the record, so you can ask database of value stored or in transaction, if there were any changes.
- third opition is the dirtiest one, because it is just cr.execute("SELECT categ_id FROM product_template WHERE id = %s", (ids[0],)) and then category_id = cr.fetchall() - it is not always good option to use that, as it asks for records already existing in database (not counting these in transaction)